# Image ClickListener works after the JustTouched Method in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I am making an 2d Android game with libGDX.

In my play screen if a person just click the screen, my game character jumps.

Now, I added a pause image in my play screen.

When I test this, I saw that if I click pause image, the game character first jump. And after that the game is paused.

But I don't want this, I want that if I click pause image, don't jump , only pause the game. How can I do that ?

This is my `update` method of my `playScreen` class :

```
    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {

        pauseImg.addListener(new ClickListener() {  // I think, these lines work after.

            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                isPaused=true; //if pause image clicked,the game will be paused
            }
        });

        if(isPaused==false){ I think these lines work firstly.
            if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                bird.jump();
            }      
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `pauseImg` listener every frame you can just do it in `create()` method.

If you will i think this should work.